# Android Studio Button Generate Textview

Tags: android, android-studio

I was checking how to use buttons to generate a text view.

in the java file they used:

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity {

    int counter = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);

        final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                counter++;

                TextView textView = new TextView(SampleActivity.this);
                textView.setText("TextView " + counter);

                linearLayout.addView(textView);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and in the layout activity they used

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So I tried to run the application, it works fine but it wouldn't generate a text view? Am I missing something.

I understand the code, they used a counter to create a `TextView` for each time (e.g. text view 1 then textview 2). But when ever I click on the button it wouldn't really do anything.

Can someone help? Would appreciate it :)

Comment: It could be there, but you can't see it. Just asking - what background have you got? Black color? A black text on a black background couldn't be visible :)

Comment: its just the standerd background

Answer (score 0):

Your TextView muse have layoutParams, according to layout_width and layout_height

sample :

```
textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: Your textview should be **0px height** and **0px width** if you do not set layout params. When you are using xml layout you can use `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. You have to do the same with java views, so use `textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.WRAP_CONTENT)); `

Comment: This is wrong, ViewGroups have `generateDefaultLayoutParams()` for case where the params are not set.

Answer (score 0):

try to add `implements View.OnClickListener` in your activity definition. I mean `public class SampleActivity extends Activity implements View.OnCLickListener{`.Whole tutorial: https://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2011/11/13/how-to-implements-onclicklistener-for-a-view-item-in-android/

Your code should looks like:

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

   private int counter = 0;

   private final LinearLayout linearLayout;
   private Button button;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);

       linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);

       button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_button);
       button.setOnClickListener(this);
   }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view.getId() == button.getId()){
            counter++;
            TextView textView = new TextView(SampleActivity.this);
            textView.setText("TextView " + counter);

            linearLayout.addView(textView);
        }         
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error. It says Cannot assign value to linearlayout but I got it to work If I changed it to not final. I also got error on (this)

Comment: on which `this` do you get an error? and what color is your background? maybe the text is with the same color?

Comment: Oh I think you should change the line `TextView textView = new TextView(SampleActivity.this);` with `TextView textView = new TextView(linearLayout.getContext());`